# Error on creating stored procedure under Oracle - PLS-00103

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, pls-00103

Im trying to create a **stored procedure that calls another a number of times**. This is done so by **using a for each loop**. All the development is under **oracle sql developer Version 3.0.04**.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Z_INBILLABILITYSERV
    IS BEGIN
      DECLARE
        ano VARCHAR2(4); 
      BEGIN
        select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) into ano from dual;
        FOR dat IN (SELECT * FROM Z_FECHOMES WHERE MES <= 
                   (select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate) from dual )and ANO = ano)
        LOOP
          call z_insertbillability(dat.periodo_inicio,dat.periodo_fim,
                                                                dat.ano,dat.mes);
        END LOOP;
      END;
    END;
```

Im having the following error:

**Error(9,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "Z_INSERTBILLABILITY" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "Z_INSERTBILLABILITY" to continue.**

If anyone have an idea or a tip i would be glad to now and would appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the word `call`; just do:

```
    LOOP
      z_insertbillability(dat.periodo_inicio,dat.periodo_fim,
                                                            dat.ano,dat.mes);
    END LOOP;
```

The error message is perhaps a bit unhelpful, but it's to be trying to show all the ways it could try to interpret the word `call`, since it doesn't recognise it as a keyword. And showing what it would expect to see next for each: as a variable name (which would be followed by `:=` for assignment; or a schema name (which would be followed by `.`); or a function/procedure name (which would be followed by `(` for the parameter list), etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you explain me why is the call not needed? in all the examples i have seen there is always the word call or exec and so far i had no problems with that.

Comment: `call` is used in JDBC calls (and maybe others); `exec` is used from SQL*Plus. Both are indications that you want to execute some PL/SQL code. Once you're inside a PL/SQL block you don't need to indicate that again.

Comment: OK, it's an "external resource". Thanks a lot Alex. Best wishes for you.